# Band Brake placed Perpendicular to the Diameter bisecting the Angle of Contact

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I was asked the question:

> A band brake is installed on a drum rotating at 250rpm and a diameter
>   of 900mm. The angle of contact is 1.5pi radians and one end of the
>   brake band is fasted to a fixed pin while the other end to the brake
>   artm is 150m from the fixed pin. The coefficient of friction is 0.25
>   and the straight brake arm is 1000mm long and is placed perpendicular
>   to the diameter bisecting the angle of contact. What should be the
>   width in milimeters of a steel band with maximum tensile stress of
>   55MPa and 3.0mm thick will be used?

Answer is 37mm.

I honestly see no way to solve this without any indication of power or force of some sort... here's my attempt

$${ S_{max} = \frac{F_1}{w\times t} }$$
$${ 55 Mpa = \frac{F_1}{w\times 3.0 mm} }$$

$${ \frac{F_1}{F_2} = e^{(\theta \times friction)} }$$
$${ \frac{F_1}{F_2} = e^{(1.5rad \times 0.25)} }$$

Trying to find F1 seems to be the flaw. There are just no formulas I know of which doesn't require either power, force, torque?

$${ T = F \times d }$$
$${ P = 2\pi T N }$$

Is the problem set flawed? What am I missing? Is there another way?